# Issue updating variables from import - Python

Tags: python, nameerror

I am creating my global variables within my Main.py and trying to update through a function located in my States.py

The targeted code in my Main.py looks like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
import States #Import created states.py

global rad
States.Update_var()
leway = 2.00/rad
```

And my States.py looks like so:

```
def Update_var():
global rad
rad = 180.000001/3.1415926
```

But when I run the code the rad variable doesn't update to the new value and I receive an error:

## NameError: global name 'rad' is not defined

I am relitively new to python and just finding my feet so any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: [Use of "global" keyword in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python) might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to update global variable by external code, you have to pass dictionary of globals to that code:

main.py:

```
import States

States.Update_var(globals())


leway = 2.00/rad
print leway
```

States.py:

```
def Update_var(dct):
    dct["rad"] = 180.000001 / 3.1415926
```

Having those two files in a directory, run:

```
$ python main.py
0.0349065842505
```

In case, it would complain about problems to import the `States` module, make sure it can be imported, e.g. by `$ export PYTHONPATH="."`

Comment: So is the global() built in? Essentially making every variable within the Update_var function global

Comment: @Ben411916 the `globals()` is built in. If you create those two files and run `python main.py`, it will print `0.0349065842505`.

Comment: Quick question, can I update the values of rad from within my main.py?

Comment: @Ben411916 Yes, you can. In top level (outside function) you can do that directly. From within functions you have to declare the variable in global scope you want to change by `global rad`.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need `global` variable to pass the value between modules just use the function's `return` value.

**Main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
import States #Import created states.py

rad = States.Update_var()
leway = 2.00/rad
```

**States.py**

```
def Update_var():
    return 180.000001/3.1415926
```

Answer (score 1):

The `global` keyword is only used to indicate that inside a context that would normally be local, the variable you're referring to is the *global* one. You're using it correctly in `States.py`, but `main.py` is putting `global rad` at the module scope. That's always wrong.

In this case, you're importing `States` and trying to use its module-level variable `rad`. You should remove the `global rad` line in `main.py` (since it's not being used correctly) and refer to that as `States.rad`

```
# states.py

rad = 0  # unset

def update_var():
    global rad
    rad = 1  # set
```

```
# main.py

import states

states.rad  # 0
states.update_var()
states.rad  # 1
```

Comment: So I wouldn't access the Update_var() function? sorry little confused is it possible to get an example using the code i submitted.

Comment: @Ben411916 I would be remiss if I didn't warn you that using global variables is code smell. Avoid this like the plague.

Comment: Thanks im just merely trying something out